# how to separate line using awk

Tags: awk, newlines

How can I separate the line as below in a csv file:

```
(12,'hello','this girl,is lovely(adorable \r\n actually)',goodbye),(13,'hello','this fruit,is super tasty (sweet actually)',goodbye)
```

to the below as 2 different rows:

```
(12,'hello','this girl,is lovely(adorable \r\n actually)',goodbye)
(13,'hello','this fruit,is super tasty (sweet actually)',goodbye)
```

I tried using:

```
awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}' test.csv
```

but it didn't work and lost a few rows.

This data is actually a SQL query and I need to extract the data and convert it into different rows using the comma after ) and before ( as row seperator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk command can do what you want:

```
awk -F '),' '{ print $1")" "\n" $2}' source.csv
```

Result:

```
(12,'hello','this girl,is lovely(adorable \r\n actually)',goodbye)
(13,'hello','this fruit,is super tasty (sweet actually)',goodbye)
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed` (and your sample input saved in a file called `./input`):

```
$ sed -e 's/),(/)\n(/g' ./input
(12,'hello','this girl,is lovely(adorable \r\n actually)',goodbye)
(13,'hello','this fruit,is super tasty (sweet actually)',goodbye)
```

This changes the comma in every `),(` to a newline.

**WARNING**: If that character sequence occurs inside your actual data, it will be changed there too.

You could do the same in `awk`, but there's little or no advantage over using `sed`:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/\),\(/,")\n(",$0)' ./input
(12,'hello','this girl,is lovely(adorable \r\n actually)',goodbye)
(13,'hello','this fruit,is super tasty (sweet actually)',goodbye)
```

Unless you're going to do further processing on the input line that requires `awk` features, just use `sed`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help..really appreciate it! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`cat test.csv | tr -d "()" | sed 's/goodbye/goodbye\n/g'`

- sed translates the string *goodbye* into newline (*\n*). You can exclude the goodbye with `sed 's/goodbye/\n/g'` the *"g"* is to do it with ALL lines not just the first match.
- `tr` is optional to delete parenthesis (you can use tr to translate them to something else without deleting them)

Answer (score 0):

Tried in python

```
a=(12,'hello','this girl,is lovely(adorable \r\n actually)',goodbye),(13,'hello','this fruit,is super tasty (sweet actually)',goodbye)

#!/usr/bin/python
import re
b=a.split("),")
for i in range(0,len(b),1):
    if i == 0:
        d=")"
        print b[i]+d
    else:
        print b[i]
```

output

```
(12,'hello','this girl,is lovely(adorable \r\n actually)',goodbye)
(13,'hello','this fruit,is super tasty (sweet actually)',goodbye)
```